# iOS 11: Presenting modal view with UINavigationBar and SerchBar—SearchBar is being cropped

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I'd like to present modally a View Controller embedded in a UINavigationBar with a search and the hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true option. When presenting on iPad, the search bar is being cropped. searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit() doesn't help. Is it possible to avoid it?

[image: SearchBar is being cropped]